# Prevent access token embedded in URL from replacing git credentials cache

Tags: git, npm

Our npm project has a git dependency that is on a private server which needs credentials. Both the project and the dependency are hosted by the same server.

Using a git dependency with credentials caused all kinds of problems: auth errors, npm adding people’s usernames to the URL in `package.json`, etc.

To try and solve this, I generated a read-only access token and embedded it in the URL as a password.

````
{
  "dependencies": {
    "myPackage": "git+https://user:myaccesstoken@example.com`
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```
````

This worked ok for running `npm install`, but then it replaced my cached git credentials (`wincred`) with the access token!

Is there a command I can run before and after the build to say something along the lines of: “Please temporarily don’t cache these credentials, but don’t forget the cache either?”

Comment: You shouldn’t be using HTTPS to access a repo like this. The issue you are facing is inherent to how HTTPS authorization works. You should use SSH keys instead. No need to do anything fancy; unless your SSH keys are associated with the Git repo there is no access. And your code just stays the same… Without the HTTPS of course.

Comment: @Giacomo good advice, I love the idea of using keys instead of passwords or access tokens. Unfortunately, we're at the mercy of our IT department, which has configured our repository management website to only provide HTTPS clone URLs. I'll put in a request though

Comment: “Unfortunately, we're at the mercy of our IT department, which has configured our repository management website to only provide HTTPS…” Wow! Definitely put in a request. And if it is refused? I would see if you can go over heads to explain how ridiculous blocking SSH access to a repo is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid having credentials saved to the credential helper, then you need to set the `credential.helper` option to the empty string.  You can do that with a syntax like `git -c credential.helper= clone URL`, but that has to be used at the time the command is invoked, which will be difficult if it's being invoked by npm.

Note that in general embedding credentials into URLs is insecure and you should avoid doing it.  There has been discussion about dropping support for this on the Git list, in fact.  You could try to use the example of [reading from the environment in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment) using a custom configuration file.  That file could look like this:

```
[credential]
    helper =
    helper = "!f() { echo username=author; echo \"password=$GIT_TOKEN\"; };f"
```

and you could then (assuming your file is `foo.cfg`), set `GIT_TOKEN` in the environment and run `GIT_CONFIG=foo.cfg npm`.  That assumes that npm does not strip its environment; if it does, then you're out of luck.

Comment: This is all solid advice, especially about not embedding credentials in URLs. At one point I did try to set credential.helper to blank in a preinstall script, and set it back in a postinstall script, but I couldn't figure out what happens during an npm install failure. Ultimately, we switched to using tarball URL dependencies published by our CICD process. That caused the fewest problems between it, git URL dependencies, and Artifactory's npm server (using alternate npm repositories, with credientials, is a _nightmare_).